# Differentiate then re arrange to find a value

Tags: derivatives

**Question:**

> The height of a body is described by:
>
> $h = \frac{\ln\left(t^2-B\right)}{a}$
>
> where  is the time in seconds and  and  are constants.
>
> a) Write  in terms of ,  and ℎ.
> b) Determine $\frac{ℎ}{}$
> c) Given that $\alpha = 0.2$ and $ = 9$, calculate the positive value of  such that $\frac{ℎ}{}=50$

**My attempt:**

Part a.  I have $t = \sqrt{\mathrm{e}^{ha}+B}$

Part b. using the chain rule I've differentiated to get :

$\frac{ℎ}{}$ $=\dfrac{2t}{a\left(t^2-B\right)}$

Now for part c. I need to use:

$50$ $=\dfrac{2t}{0.2\left(t^2-9\right)}$

Can someone show me how to rearrange to find t here, or If i have went wrong somewhere please?

Im looking for an answer of 3.102 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a linear and a quadratic power on $t$. The obvious way to start off, thus, is trying to form a quadratic equation in $t$.

On rearranging we get: $5(t^2-9)=t$  which is equal to $5t^2-t-45=0$  - a quadratic equation!

Can you solve it now?

Comment: Thanks, and using the quadratic equation i'm guessing, but my answer isn't coming out correct

Comment: Nope that's a lie i missed some brackets out, thanks!